# How do I hide the tab bar in Chromium for a smoother web app experience?

Tags: chromium, webapps

After playing around (as in forgot to install `chromium-addon` for integration and losing half a day to find that out) with unity-webapps I finally got them to work.

Problem is, if I access a web app from the starter panel, they show the standard Chromium tab bar:[image: problem]. I cannot open a new tab and if I close the tab the whole window will close (fine so far).

So I was wondering if there is a way of removing the tabbar from Webapps or configure them so that they will open in firefox (where I could hide the tabbar in options). I however don't want to use firefox as my standard browser.

Any tips?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you create the Webapp from *within* Chromium, you'll effectively have what you want.

Go to Menu/Wrench>Tools>Create Web apps and shortcuts In Chromium/Chrome. No extensions, not anything extra installed.

[image: Twitter]